# Thread freezes UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have this button that when clicked calls a thead to update user ui:

```
averageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Testing().execute();
        }
    });
```

The method gets executed but it freezes the UI for 10 seconds. I want to update the UI everytime I call the averageMiles.append(mile) method.

```
    class Testing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        int x = 0;
        while (true) {

            if (x == 10) {
                break;
            }

            ArrayList<Double> milesList = new ArrayList<>();


            if (x == 0) {
                averageMiles.setText("mph: ");
            }

            String mile = milesValue.getText().toString();
            if (!isNum(mile)) {
                continue;
            }

            averageMiles.append(mile);
            milesList.add(Double.valueOf(mile.trim()));
            x++;
            if (x == 10) {
                averageMiles.append("\nAverage: " + getAverage(milesList));
                return ;
            } else {
                averageMiles.append(", ");
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` runs on main Thread So u are the one who is making UI thread to hang . Pls read about API first before using it . Also `Asynctask` is deprecated long ago so u might wanna use some other APIs for multi threading

Answer (score 0):

Use ThreadPool executor from official oracle and android developer documentations

[Oracle Docs - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)
[Android Docs - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor)

as you have specified you are using java the above two documentation is recommended by google as show below for `AsyncTask`

> This class was deprecated in API level 30.
> Use the standard java.util.concurrent or Kotlin concurrency utilities instead.

The ultimate objective is the android is saying that, if you want to update UI, simply use `runOnUiThread` with a new runnable you update the UI, which means for each UI update you may be creating fresh short term thread which only updates the UI and thread finishes and garbage collected

### Sample Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int count = 0;
    Executor ex;
    MyThread th;

    class MyThread extends Thread implements Runnable {
        private boolean running=false;

        public void setRunning(boolean running) {
            this.running = running;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;
                        TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void onStartClick(View view) {
        th = new MyThread();
        ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        th.setRunning(true);
        ex.execute(th);
    }

    public void onStopClick(View view) {
        if(th!=null) {
            th.setRunning(false);
        }
    }
}
```

all the member variables of the class should be only accessed inside runOnUiThread, for example `count++` count is a variable of the `MainActivity` if you want any value specific to the thread you put only inside the `MyThread` class

Never try to access any of the `MainActivity` variable inside the `run()` method

You can also write `MyThread` as separate class, and set values similar to `th.setRunning` before starting the thread.

If you want a callback after the thread is completed use an interface which will give you a callback method in your `MainActivity`

So it is simply core java
I have created an example with interface
[Concurrent Executor Interface Example](https://github.com/dickensas/android-java-examples/tree/main/ConcurrentExecutorInterface)

Comment: I changed my code. I have a new thread with several handlers. I call the handlers to update the UI and then I make the new thread sleep for a while. It works but I don't know if my way is good practice.

Comment: no, android tells simply go with core java and and mix the core android code, I put the code for you, `Executor` is also core java `Thread` and `Runnable` also core java `runOnUiThread` is core android

Comment: I have updated the answer with a full example